# Multiple params in http get request

Tags: http, query-string, uri

Are urls of the form http://asdf.com/something.do?param1=true?param2=false valid?

I don't think the second ? is allowed in valid urls and that it should instead be an ampersand (&), but I'm unable to find anything about this in the http 1.1 rfc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not valid to use ? again.  ? should indicate the start of the parameter list.  & should separate parameters.

From [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> ```
> URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

From [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) :

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> http:// <host> : <port> / <path> ? <searchpart>
> ```
>
> where `<host>` and `<port>` are as described in Section 3.1. If `:<port>`
>   is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
>   allowed.  `<path>` is an HTTP selector, and `<searchpart>` is a query
>   string. The `<path>` is optional, as is the `<searchpart>` and its
>   preceding "?". If neither `<path>` nor `<searchpart>` is present, the "/"
>   may also be omitted.
>
> Within the `<path>` and `<searchpart>` components, "/", ";", "?" are
>   reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
>   hierarchical structure.

The [search part/query part is described here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

Answer (score 5):

use & for the second and third

i.e.  http://asdf.com/something.do?param1=true&param2=false

Answer (score 1):

> **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
>
> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+`, and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by `%HH`, a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A`).
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=` and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&`.
>
> — [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#didx-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it's not valid to use it again.  However, if you have the ? character as part of a parameter value, you can encode it as %63 (just like the space character which gets encoded as %20).